# Azure Bot service doesn't start

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I have tried to set up this repo: https://github.com/xtreamsrl/clockify-nlp-bot but for different reasons, this seemed to be too complex for me to start. So I have decided to follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned

Now there is a problem when I create the bot. If I follow the guide 1:1 my bot isn't starting as expected. I always get the following message:

[image]

Unfortunately, nearly every tutorial you can find on youtube uses the deprecated "Web app bot" service instead of the "Azure bot".
Do you have an idea what is going wrong there? Or how to further troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: How did you try to deploy it? With a zip file? Did you already create Azure resources before doing so? Those steps can be a bit confusing at times.

Comment: I haven‘t tried to deploy it. The problem has occurrd right after creating the service. In the meantime i figured out that the service itself is working properly. But still i can‘t access the overview page

Comment: So you followed steps 1-8 in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned) and after you created the Bot resource, you could not access it?

What happens if you change "Type of App" to "Multi-tenant" when making the Bot resource?

Comment: Yes, i was not able to access the oberview page. I did the same steps within another account and it worked as expected. It could also be a problem from microsoft

Comment: If the resource was running, it could also be something to do with permissions. Is the account where you're having problems a personal account?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems related to permissions. Probably you don't have required permission to deploy the resources.

If you are deploying resource as Azure AD user or group member, make sure you have relevant permissions. Make sure you have required permission at Subscription level and resource group level.

For me it deployed successfully.

[image]